# Prove existence of 5 non-attacking rooks

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

Problem: There are $41$  rooks on a $10\times10$ chessboard. Prove that there must exist $5$ rooks, none of which attack each other.

---

I could only observe that at least one of rows and at least one column must contain at least 5 rooks.
Please help!!

Comment: There are 41 non'attacking rooks...then what do I have to prove?

Comment: @Aniket, i meant there are 41 rooks. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: Divide the board into diagonals. Here’s an example of what I mean on a small board:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
1&2&3\\ \hline
3&1&2\\ \hline
2&3&1\\ \hline
\end{array}$$